# Adding content to a Lucene index in Zend Framework

Tags: zend-framework, indexing, lucene, frameworks

I'm developing new modules for an intranet based on Precurio, an intranet PHP + MySQL application which used to have a free version.

This intranet uses Zend Framework 2.0, and uses Lucene to provide search results. Everytime I add a new module to the intranet I add the functionality to index the contents of the module that the users insert.

The problem is, the search works ok, but ONLY if I rebuild all the indexes from scratch. Whenever I add new contents to the module, they don't come up in the search results (the contents that existed previous to the full rebuilding of the index still are shown as search results).

I'm quite puzzled, because the function that rebuilds the whole index just calls the one that adds a single item to it in a loop, so to the best of my knowledge, it should work just the same. But obviously, it does not.

This is the code of the indexing function for the module I'm currently developing:

```
/**
 * Adds a cabinet to the index
 * @param $cabinet int | CabinetContent . you could either pass the cabinet_id or the CabinetContent object
 * @return void
 */
public function indexCabinet($cabinet,$indexing = false)
{
    if(!is_a($cabinet,'CabinetContent')) {
        $cabinet = CabinetContents::getContent($cabinet);
    }

    if(Precurio_Utils::isNull($cabinet->title))
            return;//cabinets without a title will be ignored.

    //check if the cabinet already exists
    if(!$indexing)
    {
        $hits = $this->index->find('id:' . $cabinet->id.' AND module:cabinet');
        foreach ($hits as $hit) 
        {
            $this->index->delete($hit->id);
        }
    }
    try
    {
        $doc = new Zend_Search_Lucene_Document();
        $doc->addField(Zend_Search_Lucene_Field::keyword('id',$cabinet->id));
        $doc->addField(Zend_Search_Lucene_Field::text('title',$cabinet->title));
        if( $cabinet->identifier != '' )
            $doc->addField(Zend_Search_Lucene_Field::text('identifier',$cabinet->identifier));
        if( $cabinet->summary != '' )
            $doc->addField(Zend_Search_Lucene_Field::text('summary',$cabinet->summary));
        if( $cabinet->body != '' )
            $doc->addField(Zend_Search_Lucene_Field::text('body',$cabinet->body));
        $doc->addField(Zend_Search_Lucene_Field::keyword('user_id',$cabinet->user_id));
        if( ($cabinet->url != '#') && ($cabinet->url != '') )
            $doc->addField(Zend_Search_Lucene_Field::text('url',$cabinet->url));
        if( $cabinet->keyword != '' )
            $doc->addField(Zend_Search_Lucene_Field::text('keyword',$cabinet->keyword));
        if( $cabinet->getFullName() != '' )
            $doc->addField(Zend_Search_Lucene_Field::text('fullname',$cabinet->getFullName()));

        $doc->addField(Zend_Search_Lucene_Field::unIndexed('date_added',$cabinet->getDateAdded()));
        $doc->addField(Zend_Search_Lucene_Field::keyword('module','cabinet'));
    }
    catch(Exception $e)
    {

    }   

    $this->index->addDocument($doc);
    return;
}
```

The previous function only seems to work when I run createIndexFromDB(). These are the functions used to recreate the index:

```
private $index;
public function __construct()
{               
    if(!file_exists(self::PATH_INDEX)) 
        $this->createIndexFromDb();
    else 
        $this->index = Zend_Search_Lucene::open(self::PATH_INDEX);
}
private function createIndexFromDb()
{
    set_time_limit(0);
    mkdir(self::PATH_INDEX);
    $this->index = Zend_Search_Lucene::create(self::PATH_INDEX);
    $this->indexCabinets(); // Cabinets is the module I am developing 
    /* Here go a lot of indexing for other modules, like $this->indexEmployees(); but I have commented it out for simplicity during developement */
}

private function indexCabinets()
{
    $table = new Zend_Db_Table(array('name'=>PrecurioTableConstants::CABINET_CONTENT,'rowClass'=>'CabinetContent'));
    $select = $table->select(false);
    $select->setIntegrityCheck(false);
    $select->setTable($table); 

    $select = $select->distinct()
                    ->from(array('a' => PrecurioTableConstants::CABINET_CONTENT))
                    ->join(array('b' => PrecurioTableConstants::USERS),'a.user_id = b.user_id',array('first_name','last_name','profile_picture_id'))
                    ->where('a.active=1');
    $cabinets = $table->fetchAll($select);
    foreach($cabinets as $cabinet)
    {
        $this->indexCabinet($cabinet,true);
    }
}
```

Now, in the module I am developing, after inserting a new cabinet content,  I run the following code:

```
$dict = new My_Search();
$dict->indexCabinet($content_id);
$this->_redirect('/cabinet/view/index');
```

But it doesn't work. I tried to call $dict->indexCabinet with 'true' as the second parameter, also passing the $content object as they do in the search class instead of the $content_id... I don't know what I am dowing wrong, nor what else to try.

I have to make clear that all the new modules are based on the original ones in the Precurio Intranet, and also the additions in the My_Search class. For all I know, indexing new contents may not have worked in the original code. Any help will be greatly appreciated.

**Edit 10/08/2016: I added the original class constructor to the code above

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I'm not quite sure I see exactly how the code you've provided is being used (my familiarity with Zend is touch and go at the best of times), but this sounds consistent with a pretty common lucene mistake: creating a new index, rather than opening the existing one.

You should use `Zend_Search_Lucene::create` to create an *entirely new* index.  Any existing index at the given location will be deleted.

You should use `Zend_Search_Lucene::open` to open an existing index.

See the first two examples in this Zend ["Building Indexes" documentation](https://framework.zend.com/manual/1.10/en/zend.search.lucene.index-creation.html).

Comment: I'll try tomorrow at work and let you know if it worked. Thanks!

Comment: Great, that gave me the lead to get it to work by adapting the link you provided, adding at the beginning of each indexing function the following line: "$index = Zend_Search_Lucene::open(self::PATH_INDEX);" . Still, I don't get why the original code didn't work: I think it did the same, but instead of using $index, it used the class private variable $this->index, which opened the index at the constructor: $this->index = Zend_Search_Lucene::open(self::PATH_INDEX);

I edited the original question to add the constructor code